# Is there a verb for accepting a hitchhiker into your car?

Tags: word-request

The verb hitchhike mean to solicit or get (a free ride) along a road, but what about the opposite, which is accepting them into a car? Is there a verb for it?

For example:

> Jeremy ____ hitchhikers into his car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use

***TO GIVE A LIFT.***

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary :](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lift#other-words)

"***Lift***

Noun

: ASSISTANCE, HELP

: a ride especially along one's way"

This phrase would be a good match with an idiom ***HITCH  A LIFT.***

[Definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20lift) of ***hitch a lift:***

"chiefly British, informal

: to get a ride in a passing vehicle

// Her car broke down, so she had to hitch a lift with a passing truck."

Answer (score 3):

You "pick up a hitchhiker".

I wouldn't add "into his car" since that is implicit (he isn't going to put the hitchhiker on the roof!)

> Jeremy picked up some hitchhikers.
>
> In Cuba, picking up hitchhikers is mandatory for government vehicles.
>
> If you are worried about your carbon footprint, then pick up some hitchhikers to offset it a little.

You can also "offer a ride", which doesn't imply that the person accepts the ride.

> Jeremy stopped to offer a ride to the man he saw walking towards town, but the guy wasn't interested.